Unknown sequence in ruby marshal
While writing parser for ruby marshal format i notised one strange thing. At one point after a variable comes sequence "\x04\x08". By documentation this is format version. But judging by common sense it should be only at start of file. Or in ruby i can write in file multiple streams and read them without problems. Or format obusficated and i have to skip all these sequences? Or something else?

Question probably dumb but i do not know ruby and do not want to know and nobody seems asked question about this.

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/marshal_rdoc.html. If there is other documentation or better specification show me.

Marshal uses a binary format. You'll probably have to look at the source rather than the method docs for the current implementation as of Ruby 3.3.5.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

"At one point after a variable comes sequence \x04\x08" – show the whole dump, please.

There was error in code that read string data type and because of it i didn't realised that one stream holds exacly one variable. So now i know what to do.

Also i do not belive that this is proper documentation for ruby because some data types unexplained (byte sequence) and some data types explained too vaguely (string encoding, instance variable).
